# C# Asp.Net cancel a long web request by other web request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a web crawler which have to hit a given list of urls. Now i have to make a web interface to start and to stop the crawler module.

OK now i can call the module by simply making a web request ( which definitely takes a long time to complete ).

Now the problem is that how can i stop( or interrupt) the request from being completed by making a abort web request.
For this the second request has to provide a command to first request to stop, But how can two requests communicate ( or share data. )

im dangling on internet from few days but didn't find any help on the subject, please can u provide some pointers, or some alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single server running the web crawler, the simplest solution (ugly as it is) is likely to maintain a static collection of requests:

```
// assume the Request class contains the information necessary to cancel the request
// e. g. the cancellation token
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Request> Requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Request>();
```

When you make the initial request to start the crawler, it can create a Guid key for that request and store the long-running request in the static dictionary. Then you can make a future request passing that key to do the cancellation. You'll also need to make sure that requests get removed from the dictionary when they finish normally (perhaps via a separate cleanup thread or a continuation on the task which is waiting for the request to complete).

If you have multiple servers, you could still use this approach, but you'd need some solution for determining which server was running which request (e. g. a database to store the mapping or a means of broadcasting the abort request to all servers).

Comment: Please can you provide some sample code. i don't know about accessing different requests. Thanks a lot for considering.

Comment: nice answer.can you elaborate a bit more or can you attach some links to research further regarding this?